# django count annotation field

Tags: python, django, django-1.3, django-aggregation

Django 1.3, Python 2.7

I have the following models (some irrelevant fields omitted):

```
class Encounter(models.Model):
  subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject', to_field='uuid')
  uuid = models.SlugField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=make_uuid, editable=False)

class Subject(models.Model):
  uuid = models.SlugField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=make_uuid, editable=False)
```

I calculated the number of encounters per subject using the following code:

```
e_in_s = Subject.objects.annotate(revcount = Count('encounter')).order_by('-revcount')
```

Now I would like to know how many subjects have exactly `revcount` encounters for each value of `revcount`.  I tried the following:

```
sprime_in_e = e_in_s.values('revcount').annotate(countprime=Count('revcount'))
```

but got the error "Cannot compute Count('revcount'): 'revcount' is an aggregate".  Any suggestions?

Note: I need the value produced by `e_in_s` as well as its annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use annotate with annotated values. However, you can use `aggregate`. [See the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)

Your queries will look like:

```
e_in_s = Subject.objects.annotate(revcount = Count('encounter')).order_by('-revcount')
sprime_in_e = e_in_s.values('revcount').aggregate(countprime=Count('revcount'))
```

If this doesn't suffice you'll need to use the `extra` feature or drop down to raw SQL.